# Windows Server changing default administrator account name cause issues

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, administrator, group-policy

I've changed the default administrator account name to increase security on a Windows Server 2019, but now I can't run anymore some applications, like:

- Uninstall programs
- The default search bar in the taskbar
- Administrative tools

How can I solve it?! I can't even find a way to start the "run" window to run **secpol.msc** and try to restore the original username.

I've tried using powershell, but it tels me the command is wrong:

```
 C:\Users\Administrator> Rename-LocalUser -UserName 'Administrator79' -NewUserName 'Administrator'
Rename-LocalUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UserName'.
At line:1 char:18
+ Rename-LocalUser -UserName 'Administrator79' -NewUserName 'Administra ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-LocalUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameLocalUserCommand
```

Please help me, I've the server stucked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by running secpol.msc from the PowerShell and then changing back the Administrator name to its original name

Answer (score 0):

> Right click on My computer > computer management > local users and
>   groups
>
> Then select your user and provide administrative rights.
>
> I hope it will work for you